# Choose a matrix $B$ such that Tr$[B^*A]+$Tr$[BA^*]=0$ always. Is $B=0$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I wish to choose a matrix $B$ such that the following expression is equal to zero
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}[B^*A]+\text{Tr}[BA^*]=0
\end{equation}
In order for this to be true for all $A$ do I require $B=0$? This is the trivial solution but I wish to know if it is also the only solution?

Comment: If ti is true for all $A$, then it must be true for $E_{ij}$. Here $E_{ij}$ is the matrix having $1$ on the $\left( i, j \right)$-th place and $0$ everywhere else. So, What can you say about the equations you will get when you consider all possible $E_{ij}$'s?

Comment: Thank you! This shows that the real part of $B_{i,j}$ is $0$. So I need to also consider the matrix $F_{i,j}$ with $\sqrt{-1}$ as the ($i,j$)-th place to completely show this?

Comment: Correct! I think you can figure it out now, right?

Comment: Yes thank you!!